# Can't send file via ajax ( print_r($_FILES); Array ( ) )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm trying to send file, it works with common form confirm, but don't with XHR.
Here my HTML:

```
<form action="ajax/upload.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="id1">
  <input type="file" name="input1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>  

<form action="ajax/upload.php"  method="post" name="form2" id="id2">
  <input type="file" name="input2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit2">
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#id2').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = document.querySelector('#id2 input[type="file"]').files[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "ajax/upload.php", true);
    var boundary = String(Math.random()).slice(2);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

PHP:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo 'print_r($_FILES); <br>';
echo 'Result: <br><br>';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
```

I send same file, responses for common submit:

```
array(1) {
  ["submit1"]=>
  string(31) "Отправить запрос"
}
print_r($_FILES); 
Result: 

Array
(
    [input1] => Array
        (
            [name] => CRC75.otf
            [type] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbNWcgk
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 411456
        )

)
```

For AJAX:

```
array(0) {
}
print_r($_FILES); 
Result: 

Array
( 
)
```

I can't understand why, file attached exist:

```
document.querySelector('#id2 input[type="file"]').files[0]
File { name: "CRC75.otf", lastModified: 1529516347000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 411456, type: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template" }
```

Headers of AJAX request looks normal

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 411456
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=44316423440108066
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
```

*P.S.: It's the requirement that I cannot send a `POST` request.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a `File` directly in the `send()` parameter, you need to use a `FormData` object.

```
document.querySelector('#id2').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData;
    var file = document.querySelector('#id2 input[type="file"]').files[0];
    formdata.append("input2", file);
    formdata.append("submit2", "Отправить запрос");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "ajax/upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

Don't use `xhr.setRequestHeader()` to set the `Content-type` header. This is done automatically by the browser. If you do it yourself, the boundary you specify won't match what it's actually sending.

Comment: Still same result
`var file = document.querySelector('#id2 input[type="file"]').files[0];  
var formData = new FormData();  
formData.append('File', file);    
xhr.send(formData); `

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I send FormData object, but it still response as before.